# Thymeleaf + Spring Boot: Object creation with related object (Form & Return)

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I'm developing an application using Spring Boot and Thymeleaf, in which I have a Package class and a User class.

Package Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_package")
public class Package {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "gen_id", strategy = "increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "gen_id")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userid")
    @JsonBackReference
    private User package_owner;
//    private Integer userid;

    private String package_name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pkg")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Set<Article> articles;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "package_statusid")
    @JsonBackReference
    private PackageStatus packageStatus;
//    private Integer package_statusid;

    private String notes;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public User getPackage_owner() {
        return package_owner;
    }

    public void setPackage_owner(User package_owner) {
        this.package_owner = package_owner;
    }

//    public Integer getUserid() {
//        return userid;
//    }
//
//    public void setUserid(Integer userid) {
//        this.userid = userid;
//    }

    public String getPackage_name() {
        return package_name;
    }

    public void setPackage_name(String package_name) {
        this.package_name = package_name;
    }

    public Set<Article> getArticles() {
        return articles;
    }

    public void setArticles(Set<Article> articles) {
        this.articles = articles;
    }

    public PackageStatus getPackageStatus() {
        return packageStatus;
    }

    public void setPackageStatus(PackageStatus packageStatus) {
        this.packageStatus = packageStatus;
    }

    public String getNotes() {
        return notes;
    }

    public void setNotes(String notes) {
        this.notes = notes;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Package{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", package_owner=" + package_owner +
                ", package_name='" + package_name + '\'' +
                ", articles=" + articles +
                ", packageStatus=" + packageStatus +
                ", notes='" + notes + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

User Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name="gen_id" , strategy="increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="gen_id")
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "package_owner")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Set<Package> packages = new HashSet<Package>();

}
```

I'm coding a screen for the package insert

Package Add/Insert:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/packages/add}" th:object="${Package}" method="post">
    <table class="table stripped-table" id="article-table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                User:
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="user-search"/>
                <input type="text" th:value="*{user.id}" hidden="hidden" th:required="required"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Package:
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" th:field="*{package_name}" th:required="required"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Add" />
</form>
```

Before I related the objects between them I was using JavaScript's autocomplete to write the name on the 'user-search', insert the value to the user_id input and just pass that to my controller.

But now that I've created the relation between both objects every time I try to load the template I get this error:

`Invalid property 'user' of bean class [com.app.model.Package]: Bean property 'user' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?`

I've been looking at the getter and setter but can't find an issue. I'm also curious as of how the return should be handled on my controller, but that I assume would be inserting the whole object before the save function on the DB. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** Sorry for the delay, I was on a business trip.

Here's the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView addPackageForm(Model model){

    List<PackageStatus> packageStatuses = packageStatusRepository.findAll();

    model.addAttribute("Package", new Package());
    model.addAttribute("PackageStatus", packageStatuses);
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("packages/add");
    mav.addObject("page_title", "Test: Add Package");
    mav.addObject("template_primary", "packages");
    mav.addObject("template_secondary", "add");
    return mav;
}
```

Comment: I recommend you the MVC pattern

Comment: If you use 'package_owner' instead of user, does it work? My reasoning is that you don't have a field named 'user' in package, only a 'User' field name 'package_owner'.

Comment: Can you show us the controller ?

Comment: Again, sorry for the delay, I edited the post to add the controller (or at least the corresponding part. Outside of that is just repository autowiring.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the proper field name of your class, so switch `user` for `package_owner` or as you did in your comment, you can do the opposite.

Comment: I actually did the opposite, just changed the instance name of user from `package_owner` to `user`but yeah, it worked.